# HAproxy as ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, haproxy, amazon-eks, haproxy-ingress

What kind of load balancing HAproxy ingress controller capable of.
Can it do load balancing on a Pod level ? or it does it on a Node level load-balancing.

Thanks 
Yaniv

Answer (score 1):

An ingress provides load balancing, name based virtual hosting, SSL/TLS termination. Yes, it will do load balancing on services ( backed by pods ). Here is the sample Ingress kubernetes object manifest file.

```
Example:

 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
     name: sample-ingress
     annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
 spec:
     rules:
     - host: foo.bar.com
       http:
          paths:
          - path: /foo
            backend:
                serviceName: service1 ( Backed by service1 pod )
                servicePort: 4200
          - path: /bar
            backend:
                serviceName: service2  ( Backed by service2 pod )
                servicePort: 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/1-9r1/traffic-management/kubernetes-ingress-controller/#haproxy-ingress-controller-features):

> The ingress controller gives you the ability to:
>
> - Use only one IP address and port and direct requests to the correct pod based on the Host header and request path
> - Secure communication with built-in SSL termination
> - Apply rate limits for clients while optionally whitelisting IP addresses
> - **Select from among any of HAProxy's load-balancing algorithms**
> - Get superior Layer 7 observability with the HAProxy Stats page and Prometheus metrics
> - Set maximum connection limits to backend servers to prevent overloading services

Also I recommend the following resources:

- [HAProxy Kubernetes Ingress Controller](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/dissecting-the-haproxy-kubernetes-ingress-controller/)

> L7 routing is one of the core features of Ingress, allowing incoming
>   requests to be routed to the exact pods that can serve them based on
>   HTTP characteristics such as the requested URL path. Other features
>   include terminating TLS, using multiple domains, and, most
>   importantly, load balancing traffic.

- [GitHub](https://github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress)

I hope it helps.